# Ebean One to Many Mapping not working.

Tags: orm, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am writing a web app that has products, customers, credit cards and a cart. Customer has a one to many mapping on both credit cards and carts. In my customer class i have a list and list. When i access customer.creditCardList everything works. When i try the same for customer.shoppingCartList i get this error.

```
error] Test models.ModelsTest.createAndRetrieveCart failed: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[Field 'customer_id' doesn't have a default value]
```

Before i was getting no error but my shoppingCartList was always empty even with items in the database.

Here is my test function which is throwing the error:

@Test

```
public void createAndRetrieveCart(){
    Customer walter = Customer.find.where().eq("email", "test@banananow.com").findUnique();
    Product p1 = Product.find.where().idEq(1).findUnique();
    Product p2 = Product.find.where().idEq(2).findUnique();

    new ShoppingCart(walter, p1, 2).save();
    new ShoppingCart(walter, p2, 3).save();

    if(walter.shoppingCartList.size() < 2){
        assert(false);
    }
    for(ShoppingCart cart : walter.shoppingCartList){
        assertNotNull(cart.product.name);
        assertNotNull(cart.product.price);
        System.out.println(cart.product.name);
        System.out.println(cart.product.price);
        System.out.println(cart.quantity);

    }
}
```

The error occurs on line 123 which is the first ShoppingCart.save()
The weird part is almost identical code for creditCardList passes and works properly. Here is that test

```
public void createAndAddCreditCard(){
        Customer walter = Customer.find.where().eq("email", "tester@test.com").findUnique();
        //Date date = new Date(2017, 10, 1);
        //new CreditCard(1234567812345679L, walter, "walter wooodall", date, 21919, 123).save();
        for(CreditCard card : walter.creditCardList){
           System.out.println(card.number);
        }
    }
```

Here are my models:

Customer:

```
@Entity
public class Customer extends Model {

    @Id
    public int id;
    public String email;
    public String password;
    public String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="address_id")
    public Address address;
    public double balance;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    public List<CreditCard> creditCardList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    public List<Basket> basketList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    public List<ShoppingCart> shoppingCartList;

    public Customer(String email, String password, String name, Address address){
        this.email = email.toLowerCase();
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name.toLowerCase();
        this.address = address;
        this.balance = 0.0;
        //this.creditCardList = new ArrayList<CreditCard>();
        //this.shoppingCartList = new ArrayList<ShoppingCart>();
    }

    public static Finder<String, Customer> find = new Finder<String, Customer>(String.class, Customer.class);

    public static Customer authenticate(String email, String password) {
        return find.where().eq("email", email)
                .eq("password", password).findUnique();
    }

    public static Customer exists(String email) {
        return find.where().eq("email", email).findUnique();
    }

    /*
    public List<CreditCard> getCreditCardList(){
        return CreditCard.find.where().eq("customer_id", this.id).findList();
    }
    */
}
```

ShopppingCart:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="shopping_cart")
public class ShoppingCart extends Model{
    @Id
    public int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Customer customer;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Product product;
    public int quantity;


    public ShoppingCart(Customer customer, Product product, int quantity){
        this.customer = customer;
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public static Finder<String, ShoppingCart> find = new Finder<String, ShoppingCart>(String.class, ShoppingCart.class);


}
```

Product:

```
@Entity
public class Product extends Model{
    @Id
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public Float price;
    public String category;
    public String subcategory;
    @Column(name = "image_url")
    public String imageUrl;
    public String url;
    @ManyToOne
    public Store store;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product")
    public List<BasketProduct> basket_product;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    public List<ShoppingCart> shoppingCartList;

    public Product(String name, Float price, String category, String subcategory, String imageUrl, String url, Store store){
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.category = category;
        this.subcategory = subcategory;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.url = url;
        this.store = store;
    }

    public Product(int id, String name, Float price, String category, String subcategory, String imageUrl, String url, Store store){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.category = category;
        this.subcategory = subcategory;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.url = url;
        this.store = store;
    }

    public static Finder<String, Product> find = new Finder<String, Product>(String.class, Product.class);

    public static List<Product> getTopProducts(){
        String sql = "select * from top_product";
        SqlQuery sqlQuery = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql);
        List<SqlRow> sqlRows = sqlQuery.findList();
        List<Product> productList = null;
        if(sqlRows != null){
            productList = new LinkedList<Product>();
            for(SqlRow row : sqlRows){
                int id = row.getInteger("id");
                String name = row.getString("name");
                float price = row.getFloat("price");
                String category = row.getString("category");
                String subcategory = row.getString("subcategory");
                String imageUrl = row.getString("image_url");
                String url = row.getString("url");
                String storeId = row.getString("store_id");
                productList.add(new Product(id, name, price, category, subcategory, imageUrl, url, Store.find.byId(storeId)));
            }
        }
        return productList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", price=" + price +
                ", category='" + category + '\'' +
                ", subcategory='" + subcategory + '\'' +
                ", image_url='" + imageUrl + '\'' +
                ", url='" + url + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I have id, customer_id, product_id and quantity in my table with FK references to customer and product.

Anyone else have this problem and know how to solve??

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029290/persistenceexception-error-executing-dml-bindlog-errorfield-id-doesnt-hav)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like following line doesn't read customer:

```
Customer walter = Customer.find.where().eq("email", "test@banananow.com").findUnique();
```

Your second test works good but you are querying for customer with different email there. So try to change previous line to:

```
Customer walter = Customer.find.where().eq("email", "tester@test.com").findUnique();
```

Socond problem is that you have:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

This is why these relations are not saved. Remove these lines.